# Interpreting Over-dispersion test for Poisson regression

Tags: r, regression, poisson-regression, overdispersion

I did the over-dispersion test for my Poisson regression model in R, to check whether negative binominal is a better option.

I used  `stats`  package for conducting Poisson regression and  `AER`  package for testing overdispersion.

```
dispersiontest(m2.int,trafo=1)
```

Below is the output of the test

```
Overdispersion test

data:  m1.int
z = 8.0174, p-value = 0.0000000000000005401
alternative hypothesis: true alpha is greater than 0
sample estimates:
   alpha 
0.5118541
```

I don't know how to interpret the result. Does the significant p-value mean that the model is over-dispersed?

Comment: Yes ............

Comment: @noone Please see `?AER::dispersiontest` to understand how the null and alternative hypotheses are defined. By default, you are testing for overdispersion (`alternative = "greater"`) with α > 0. With that in mind, the output is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Why not add that (along with an explicit 'yes') as an answer? [Even short answers are worth posting as answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/is-a-quick-and-dirty-answer-better-than-no-answer) and [not as comments](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2642/121522)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the significant p-value mean that the model is over-dispersed?

Yes.

If you inspect `?AER::dispersiontest` you will see that the function assesses

> the hypothesis that this assumption holds (equidispersion) against the alternative that the variance is of the form:
> $$
> \mathrm{Var}[y] = \mu + \alpha \cdot\mathrm{trafo}(\mu)\,.
> $$

By default (`alternative = "greater"`), `AER::dispersiontest` checks for overdispersion ($\alpha > 0$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is really helpful.

Comment: @noone If this answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the green tick mark to the left of the answer.